# Dropdown floating inside navbar when navbar is collapsed mdboostrap

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

I am using **MDB Version: 8.0.0**. I have added `fixed-top` class on the navbar. The dropdown is floating inside the navbar in mobile devices (You have to scroll down inside the navbar to access the dropdown. When I remove the class `fixed-top`, the dropdown is floating above the navbar, the behaviour I want.

I have tried the solution `.navbar-nav { .dropdown-menu-right.dropdown-menu { left: unset; } }` provided here, https://mdbootstrap.com/support/angular/fixed-navigation-drop-down-menu-right-out-of-screen/ but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code. If you would like to try out my code, remember to remove `*ngIf="isLoggedIn"` for the dropdown to show

```
<!--Navbar-->
<mdb-navbar SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color fixed-top">
<!-- Navbar brand -->
<mdb-navbar-brand><a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">Navbar</a></mdb-navbar-brand>
<!-- Collapsible content -->
<links>
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
            <a
            routerLink="/my-orders"
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect>My Orders</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
            <a
            routerLink="/order"
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect>Order</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Links -->

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
            <a
            routerLink="/sign-in"
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect>Sign In</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
            <a
            routerLink="/sign-up"
            class="nav-link waves-light"
            mdbWavesEffect>Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Dropdown -->
        <li *ngIf="isLoggedIn" class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown>
            <a dropdownToggle mdbWavesEffect type="button" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>
            <mdb-icon fas icon="user"></mdb-icon> Account<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown dropdown-primary" role="menu">
            <a routerLink="/logout" class="dropdown-item waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Log out</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</links>
<!-- Collapsible content -->
```

**Screenshots**

Laptop. No issue.

[image: Current behaviour on laptop. Working as expected]

Current behaviour on mobile. I have to scroll down inside the navbar to access the dropdown.

[image: Current behaviour on mobile]

Expected behaviour on mobile (Working when I remove `fixed-top`)

[image: Expected behaviour on mobile]

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to utilize the mdbootstrap [display property](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/utilities/display/) like so:

```
<!--Navbar Desktop-->
<mdb-navbar class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-block d-lg-block" SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color fixed-top">
</mdb-navbar>
<!--Navbar Desktop-->

<!--Navbar Mobile-->
<mdb-navbar class="d-none d-sm-block d-md-none d-lg-none" SideClass="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark primary-color"> //removed fixed-top
</mdb-navbar> 
<!--Navbar Mobile-->
```